# Force an element never to lose focus on HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I'm programming an online editor. To get character inputs correctly I'm using jQuery.onKeyPress event on a textarea element (getting inputs from the body doesn't work, as characters such as backspace activate certain browser shortcuts - also, some characters are only provided correctly this way). That textarea is hidden by positioning it outside the window (otherwise won't work).

Questions are:

1. Is there a better design for what I'm doing?
2. How can I guarantee that this element is never defocused, other than setting a timer to focus it constantly?

Comment: Please don't: it's a *horrible* thing to do to your users if there's ever *anything* else they might want to interact with. Including buttons and links as well as other inputs.

Comment: @DavidThomas - That won't work. The `blur` event is fired *before* the element loses focus.

Comment: @Joseph: oh, really? I saw the `setTimeout()` in your answer and wondered why it was there (this would explain that...). I withdraw that suggestion, but I stand by my "but don't..." portion of the comment. =)

Comment: @DavidThomas but otherwise I won't be able to get inputs. I can't actually use a textarea for the editor part as it has syntax coloring and stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make sure the element is always in focus, use this:

```
var $textarea = $('textarea');

$textarea.on('blur', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $textarea.focus();
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: works for mobile when you don't want to lose the softkeyboard cause you clicked a button, really helped me out here thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A small variant of the answer above:

**html:**

```
<input type="text" id="element">
```

### Jquery

---

```
$('#element').on('blur', function () {
    _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        _this.focus();
    }, 0);
});
```

### Vanilla (Plain Js)

---

```
var theElement = document.getElementById("element");

theElement.addEventListener("focusout", function(){
    _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        _this.focus();
    }, 0);
});
```